# Adding HTML tags between Try block in JSP

Tags: html, jsp, servlets

I am trying a build a JSP page which i wish to display the result of the database query sent from JSP, in a table. So i tried adding the html code in the try block on JSP page. But since i have to terminate the java code with tag "%>" before the html tags, the catch block is giving an error that there's no Try block.

I am not sure how to handle this.

Below is snippet from my code:

```html
 PreparedStatement pst;
    pst=con.prepareStatement("Select * from Certificate");
    ResultSet rs;
    rs=pst.executeQuery();
    
    while(rs.next()){
        
      %>  
        <table>
            <form action="Changes.jsp">
                <tr><select name="domain"></tr>
                <tr><select value="<%rs.getString(1);%>"><%rs.getString(1);%></select></tr>
        <tr><td><input type="submit" value="Edit"></td><td><input type="reset" value="Clear"></td></tr>
        
        
                
            </form>
            
        </table>
    }
    
    <%
   
    
}catch(SQLException e){
    out.println(e);
}
```

Comment: Check this https://www.roseindia.net/jsp/simple-jsp-example/select-query-in-jsp.shtml

Comment: Well, there is no `try`, is it?

Comment: Actually there is try, i just missed to add in the snippet. I just solved it by sending the jdbc query in servlet and passing on the response of database query to the JSP for display.